Is there a ternary Cayley graph on $27$ vertices that is a non-complete core?
I am thankful for feedback given to me, through comments on one question on MSE that I have deleted and also through responses to my question on Meta. With this feedback, I am rewriting another question that I have deleted, adding some context, and hopefully this will be a better question on MSE.
Is there a non-complete ternary Cayley graph that is a core with $3^3 = 27$ vertices?
Definition. By a ternary Cayley graph, I mean a (simple, undirected) graph whose vertex set is an elementary finite abelian $3$-group, thus its vertex set is necessarily isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3^n := \bigoplus_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ for some nonnegative integer $n$, and whose edges are determined by a so-called connection set $C \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_3^n \setminus \{0\}$ that is closed under taking negation, i.e. $-C = C$. Namely, two vertices $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}_3^n$ are adjacent if and only if $x - y \in C$.
Note that the condition $-C = C$ ensures that the adjacency relation is symmetric, thus the Cayley graph is undirected. That $C$ does not contain the zero vector ensures that there are no loops. The Cayley graph on $\mathbb{Z}_3^n$ with connection set $C$ is denoted by $\mathrm{Cay}(\mathbb{Z}_3^n, C)$.
Definition. A graph is a core if all its endomorphisms are automorphisms.
By an endomorphism of a graph $X = (V, E)$ is meant an endomap $f : V \to V$ of its vertex set such that edges are sent to edges, i.e. if $x$ and $y$ are adjacent in $X$, then $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are adjacent in $X$. An automorphism is simply an invertible endomorphism, as usual.
The context of this question is that,

it can be shown that every ternary Cayley graph core with at most $3^2= 9$ vertices is necessarily complete.
I won't give a proof here, but if there is sufficient interest in a proof, I can add one in a later edit.

I conjecturely propose that the following Cayley graph with $3^3$ vertices is a noncomplete core:
$$\mathrm{Cay}(\mathbb{Z}_3^3, \{i, 2i, j, 2j, k, 2k, i +j, 2i + 2j, i + k, 2i + 2k, i + j + k, 2i + 2j + 2k\}).$$
where $i = (1, 0, 0)$, $j = (0, 1, 0)$, $k = (0, 0, 1)$. However, I am happy to get any other construction on $3^3$ vertices.

What means "complete"?

A graph is complete if any two distinct vertices are adjacent.

For $d < 3$, the only ternary Cayley graph with $3^d$ vertices that is a core is the complete graph $K_{3^d}$.

When $d=3$, the complete graph $K_{3^d} = K_{27}$ is a ternary Cayley graph core. My question asks whether there is any other ternary Cayley graph core with 27 vertices.

I don't understand how the complete graph $K_{27}$ is a core. According to the definition, in this case any map $f:V\to V$ sends edges to edges (since every pair is an edge). On the other hand, the empty graph on $27$ vertices is a core

A complete (simple) graph is a core since two distinct vertices cannot be mapped onto the same vertex as there are no loops.

The empty graph with more than one vertex is not a core since the map that sends all the vertices to a fixed vertex is a non-surjective endomorphism.
